# Why isn't my guessing a number program stopping randomly while executing?

Tags: python

I have created a few lines of code that just asks you to pick a number between 1 and 100 and you try to guess it! If it's not right the program will inform you if your guess is too high, or too low. For some reason, my program just stops for no apparent reason after about the 3rd or 4th, or 5th guess. It doesn't make any sense why it just stops all of a sudden. Can someone please explain why my program is behaving this way?

```
from random import randint
randomNum = randint(1,100)
ask_num = int(input("Guess a random number within 100: "))
while ask_num > randomNum:
    ask_num = int(input('Too High\nTry again: '))
    if ask_num < randomNum:
        ask_num = int(input('Too Low\nTry again: ')) 
    elif ask_num == randomNum:
        print('You guessed correctly!!')
        break
```

Comment: I think that may have fixed it? I'm not sure though because once I guess the number it doesn't inform me? It just closes out of the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from random import randint

randomNum = randint(1,10)
ask_num = int(input("Guess a random number within 10: "))
game_on = True

while game_on:
    if ask_num < randomNum:
        ask_num = int(input('Too Low\nTry again: '))
    elif ask_num > randomNum:
        ask_num = int(input('Too High\nTry again: ')) 
    else: 
        print('You guessed correctly!!')
        game_on = False
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
from random import randint

randomNum = randint(1,100)
ask_num = int(input("Guess a random number within 100: "))
while ask_num != randomNum:
    if ask_num < randomNum:
        ask_num = int(input('Too Low\nTry again: ')) 
    elif ask_num > randomNum:
        ask_num = int(input('Too High\nTry again: '))

print('You guessed correctly!!')
```

Or try this.

```
from random import randint

randomNum = randint(1,100)
print("Guess a random number within 100: ",end='')

while ask_num != randomNum:

    ask_num = int(input())
    if ask_num == randomNum:
        print('You guessed correctly!!')

    elif ask_num < randomNum:
        print('Too Low\nTry again: ',end='')

    elif ask_num > randomNum:
        print('Too High\nTry again: ',end='')
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is when `randomNum` and `ask_num` are the same from the beginning. The user won't know. Regards.

Comment: @LuisAlejandroVargasRamos even though they are same from the beginning I get `You guessed correctly!!`

Comment: I just noticed the indentation of your last `else`. Cheers!

Comment: the `while` has no breaks... so it will always hit the `else` making the else redundant, just remove it and print the message when you exit the loop ...

Comment: (I had already upvoted it even before, since even with it(the else), the question was answered)